# Trigonometry - worm thread related word problem

Tags: trigonometry, word-problem

### The Question

> The machine tool diagram shows a symmetric worm
> thread, in which a circular roller of diameter 1.5 inches sits.
> Find the amount d that the top of the roller rises above the
> top of the thread, given the information in the diagram. (Hint:
> Extend the slanted sides of the thread until they meet at a point.)
>
> [image][[image: 2]

### My Understanding

I found *w* and *h* using basic trig

For *w*

$$\sin15°= \frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}} = \frac{0.75}{w}$$   $$w = \frac{0.75}{\sin15°}$$ $$\sin15°= \frac{\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2}}{4}$$
$$\Longrightarrow w = 2.897$$

For h $$\tan15° =  \frac{0.85}{h}$$ $$h = 3.172$$

$$h-w = 0.2744$$

I've been trying to find angles I could use, but nothing comes to mind, so I'll be grateful if you give me some hints. English is not my first language, so sorry for possible mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$d=r-(h-w)=0.75-0.2744=0.4756$$

Comment: Thank you really, but the thing is don't understand where this comes from.

Comment: @Anna You haven't looked hard enough at the diagram you drew.

Comment: Maybe.. I figured out that r-d = h-w, but how to write this mathematically (i mean how to prove it)

Comment: @Anna With geometry, the proof _is_ the diagram.

Comment: Okey, thank you

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

From the diagram, we have $h+d=r+w$. Rearrange to find $d$:
$$d=...?$$

Can you finish it from there? If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Thank you, I've already solved the problem. I sort of made the simple part hard for myself and got stuck.

Comment: @Anna ah, ok then, great!